# How can you conditionally format a control on a subform based on a dlookup into a query?

Tags: runtime-error

I have a subform for order items where part numbers are entered into a combo box.  The combo box already limits the list to valid part numbers.

But on older records/orders part numbers may have been entered in that were valid at the time of data entry but are no longer valid.

When a user opens this continuous form for an older order how can I format the back color to red if the part number is no longer valid?

I tried putting the below code in the subform's on current event but I am getting a runtime 2471 error.

```
    If DLookup("PN", "qryCheckSOPN", "SOPN=" & _
    [Forms]![frmSalesOrderEntryCabs]![sfrmLineItemsDE].[Form]![cboPN]) Is Null Then
        Me.cboPN.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
       Me.cboPN.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
```

Comment: I also tried the conditional formatting by entering in DLookUp("PN","qryCheckSOPN","SOPN=" & [Forms]![frmSalesOrderEntryCabs]![sfrmLineItemsDE].[Form]![cboPN]) Is Null but this isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using conditional formatting and adding the Nz function instead of looking for a null value:
Nz(DLookUp("PN","qryCheckSOPN","SOPN='" & [Forms]![frmSalesOrderEntryCabs]![sfrmLineItemsDE].[Form]![cboPN] & "'"),0)=0 And [Forms]![frmSalesOrderEntryCabs]![sfrmLineItemsDE].[Form]![LineItemNumber]>0

I had to add the second part so new (blank) records were not highlighted.